# Add a row in a sorted data frame : which solutions?

Tags: r, dataframe

There is something I don't understand.
I've this data frame :

```
    Var1        Freq
1   2008-05     1
2   2008-07     7
3   2008-08     5
4   2008-09     3
```

I need to append a row on second position, for exemple it would be :

```
2008-06     0
```

I followed this ([Add a new row in specific place in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249903/add-a-new-row-in-specific-place-in-a-dataframe)). First step : add an index column ; second step : append rows with  an index number for each ; then, sort it.

```
df$ind <- seq_len(nrow(df))
df <- rbind(df,data.frame(Var1 = "2008-06", Freq = "0",ind=1.1))
df <- df[order(df$ind),]
```

Ok, everything seems good. Even if I don't know why a column called "row.names" has appeared, I get :

```
    row.names   Var1       Freq   ind
 1      1       2008-05     1      1 
 2      5       2008-06     0      1.1
 3      2       2008-07     7      2
 4      3       2008-08     5      3
 5      4       2008-09     3      4
```

Now, I plot it, with ggplot2.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = Freq, x = Var1)) + geom_bar()
```

Here we are. On the X axis, "2008-06" is placed at the end, after "2008-09" (ie with the index 5). In clear, the data frame has not been sorted, in despite of it seems to be.

Where I'm wrong ? Thanks for help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df$Var1 <- factor(df$Var1, df$Var1[order(df$ind)])
```

If you want `ggplot2` to order labels, you have to specify the ordering yourself.

You might also want to look into converting `Var1` to some sort of date class, then dispensing with the index variable altogether. This would makes things clearer, I think. The `zoo` package actually has a nice class for representing months of a given year, and you could use this for `Var1`. For example:

```
library(zoo)
df$Var1 <- as.yearmon(df$Var1)
df <- rbind(df,data.frame(Var1 = as.yearmon("2008-06"), Freq = "0"))
```

Now you can just order your data frame by `Var1` without having to worry about keeping an index:

```
> df[order(df$Var1), ]
      Var1 Freq
1 May 2008    1
5 Jun 2008    0
2 Jul 2008    7
3 Aug 2008    5
4 Sep 2008    3
```

A plot in `ggplot2` will turn out as expected:

```
ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(Var1), Freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: The resulting plot.]

Though you do have to convert `Var1` to `Date`, since `ggplot2` doesn't understand `yearmon` objects.

Comment: In my experience, if you pass factors to ggplot2 and care about their order, it's better to create an ordered factor: `factor(df$Var1, df$Var1[order(df$ind)], ordered=TRUE)`. However, I agree with using Date class here.

Comment: For sorting by date, I've tested : `df[order(as.Date(df$Var1, format="%Y-%m")),]` which print my data frame, without any errors, but without any sorting...

Comment: I don't reaaly understand what this command do, but it works ! What do you mean with ggplot ? I'm lost... :/

Comment: I updated my answer to provide an example of using dates. Jonathan, that should make things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It is because somewhere along the way you got a factor in the mix.  This produces what you're after (without the rownames column):

```
df <- read.table(text="    Var1        Freq
1   2008-05     1
2   2008-07     7
3   2008-08     5
4   2008-09     3", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$ind <- seq_len(nrow(df))
df <- rbind(df,data.frame(Var1 = "2008-06", Freq = "0",ind=1.1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
df <- df[order(df$ind),]

ggplot(df, aes(y = Freq, x = Var1)) + geom_bar()
```

Notice the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`?

As far as the order goes if you already have factors (as you do) you need to reorder the factor.  If you want more detailed info see [this post](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/)