# How to append rows to an R data frame

Tags: r, merge, append, dataframe, rows

I have looked around StackOverflow, but I cannot find a solution specific to my problem, which involves appending rows to an R data frame.

I am initializing an empty 2-column data frame, as follows.

```
df = data.frame(x = numeric(), y = character())
```

Then, my goal is to iterate through a list of values and, in each iteration, append a value to the end of the list. I started with the following code.

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    df$x = rbind(df$x, i)
    df$y = rbind(df$y, toString(i))
}
```

I also attempted the functions `c`, `append`, and `merge` without success. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

*Update from comment:*
I don't presume to know how R was meant to be used, but I wanted to ignore the additional line of code that would be required to update the indices on every iteration and I cannot easily preallocate the size of the data frame because I don't know how many rows it will ultimately take. Remember that the above is merely a toy example meant to be reproducible. Either way, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: If you want to CONCATENATE dataframes, [this is the answer you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169323/r-concatenate-two-dataframes)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

#### Update

Not knowing what you are trying to do, I'll share one more suggestion: Preallocate vectors of the type you want for each column, insert values into those vectors, and then, at the end, create your `data.frame`.

Continuing with Julian's `f3` (a preallocated `data.frame`) as the fastest option so far, defined as:

```
# pre-allocate space
f3 <- function(n){
  df <- data.frame(x = numeric(n), y = character(n), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  for(i in 1:n){
    df$x[i] <- i
    df$y[i] <- toString(i)
  }
  df
}
```

Here's a similar approach, but one where the `data.frame` is created as the last step.

```
# Use preallocated vectors
f4 <- function(n) {
  x <- numeric(n)
  y <- character(n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    x[i] <- i
    y[i] <- i
  }
  data.frame(x, y, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
```

`microbenchmark` from the "microbenchmark" package will give us more comprehensive insight than `system.time`:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(1000), f3(1000), f4(1000), times = 5)
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr         min          lq      median         uq         max neval
#  f1(1000) 1024.539618 1029.693877 1045.972666 1055.25931 1112.769176     5
#  f3(1000)  149.417636  150.529011  150.827393  151.02230  160.637845     5
#  f4(1000)    7.872647    7.892395    7.901151    7.95077    8.049581     5
```

`f1()` (the approach below) is incredibly inefficient because of how often it calls `data.frame` and because growing objects that way is generally slow in R. `f3()` is much improved due to preallocation, but the `data.frame` structure itself might be part of the bottleneck here. `f4()` tries to bypass that bottleneck without compromising the approach you want to take.

---

#### Original answer

This is really not a good idea, but if you wanted to do it this way, I guess you can try:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  df <- rbind(df, data.frame(x = i, y = toString(i)))
}
```

Note that in your code, there is one other problem:

- You should use `stringsAsFactors` if you want the characters to not get converted to factors. Use: `df = data.frame(x = numeric(), y = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem. Why is this "really not a good idea"? And in what way are x and y mixed in the for loop?

Comment: @user2932774, It's incredibly inefficient to grow an object this way in R. An improvement (but still not necessarily the best way) would be to preallocate a `data.frame` of the ultimate size you expect and add the values in with `[` extraction/replacement.

Comment: Thanks, Ananda. I normally go with preallocation, but I disagree that this is really not a good idea. It depends on the situation. In my case, I'm dealing with small data and the alternative will be more time-consuming to code. Plus, this is more elegant code compared to that required to update numerical indices to fill the appropriate portions of the pre-allocated data frame on every iteration. Just curious, what is the "best way" to accomplish this task in your opinion? I would have thought that preallocation would have been best.

Comment: @user2932774, it's cool. I appreciate your perspective too--I pretty much never really work with big datasets either. That said, if I'm going to work on writing a function or something, I would usually spend a little bit extra effort trying to tweak the code to get better speeds whenever possible. See my update for an example of a pretty huge speed difference.

Comment: Whoa, that's a huge difference! Thanks for running that simulation and teaching me about the microbenchmark package. I definitely agree with you that it's nice to put in that extra effort. In my particular case, I guess I just wanted something quicka and dirty on some code that I might never have to run again. :)

Comment: @AnandaMahto: using `rbind` was inefficient when people run R on a Commodore 64. :-)

Answer (score 35):

Let's benchmark the three solutions proposed:

```
# use rbind
f1 <- function(n){
  df <- data.frame(x = numeric(), y = character())
  for(i in 1:n){
    df <- rbind(df, data.frame(x = i, y = toString(i)))
  }
  df
}
# use list
f2 <- function(n){
  df <- data.frame(x = numeric(), y = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  for(i in 1:n){
    df[i,] <- list(i, toString(i))
  }
  df
}
# pre-allocate space
f3 <- function(n){
  df <- data.frame(x = numeric(1000), y = character(1000), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  for(i in 1:n){
    df$x[i] <- i
    df$y[i] <- toString(i)
  }
  df
}
system.time(f1(1000))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.33    0.00    1.32 
system.time(f2(1000))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.19    0.00    0.19 
system.time(f3(1000))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.14    0.00    0.14
```

The best solution is to pre-allocate space (as intended in R). The next-best solution is to use `list`, and the worst solution (at least based on these timing results) appears to be `rbind`.

Comment: Thanks! Though I disagree with Ananda's suggestion. Whether I want the characters to be converted to levels of a factor or not will depend on what I want to do with the output. Though I guess that with the solution you propose, it is necessary to set stringsAsFactors to FALSE.

Comment: Thanks for the simulation. I realize that preallocation is best in terms of processing speed, but that is not the only factor that I considered in making this coding decision.

Comment: In f1 you confused by assigning string to numeric vector x. Correct line is: `df <- rbind(df, data.frame(x = i, y = toString(i)))`

Answer (score 19):

Suppose you simply don't know the size of the data.frame in advance. It can well be a few rows, or a few millions. You need to have some sort of container, that grows dynamically. Taking in consideration my experience and all related answers in SO I come with 4 distinct solutions:

1. **`rbindlist` to the data.frame**
2. **Use `data.table`'s fast `set` operation and couple it with manually doubling the table when needed.**
3. **Use `RSQLite` and append to the table held in memory.**
4. **`data.frame`'s own ability to grow and use custom environment (which has reference semantics) to store the data.frame so it will not be copied on return.**

Here is a test of all the methods for both small and large number of appended rows. Each method has 3 functions associated with it:

- `create(first_element)` that returns the appropriate backing object with `first_element` put in.
- `append(object, element)` that appends the `element` to the end of the table (represented by `object`).
- `access(object)` gets the `data.frame` with all the inserted elements.

### `rbindlist` to the data.frame

That is quite easy and straight-forward:

```
create.1<-function(elems)
{
  return(as.data.table(elems))
}

append.1<-function(dt, elems)
{ 
  return(rbindlist(list(dt,  elems),use.names = TRUE))
}

access.1<-function(dt)
{
  return(dt)
}
```

### `data.table::set` + manually doubling the table when needed.

I will store the true length of the table in a `rowcount` attribute.

```
create.2<-function(elems)
{
  return(as.data.table(elems))
}

append.2<-function(dt, elems)
{
  n<-attr(dt, 'rowcount')
  if (is.null(n))
    n<-nrow(dt)
  if (n==nrow(dt))
  {
    tmp<-elems[1]
    tmp[[1]]<-rep(NA,n)
    dt<-rbindlist(list(dt, tmp), fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)
    setattr(dt,'rowcount', n)
  }
  pos<-as.integer(match(names(elems), colnames(dt)))
  for (j in seq_along(pos))
  {
    set(dt, i=as.integer(n+1), pos[[j]], elems[[j]])
  }
  setattr(dt,'rowcount',n+1)
  return(dt)
}

access.2<-function(elems)
{
  n<-attr(elems, 'rowcount')
  return(as.data.table(elems[1:n,]))
}
```

### SQL should be optimized for fast record insertion, so I initially had high hopes for `RSQLite` solution

This is basically copy&paste of [Karsten W. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11486898/1261153) on similar thread.

```
create.3<-function(elems)
{
  con <- RSQLite::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
  RSQLite::dbWriteTable(con, 't', as.data.frame(elems))
  return(con)
}

append.3<-function(con, elems)
{ 
  RSQLite::dbWriteTable(con, 't', as.data.frame(elems), append=TRUE)
  return(con)
}

access.3<-function(con)
{
  return(RSQLite::dbReadTable(con, "t", row.names=NULL))
}
```

### `data.frame`'s own row-appending + custom environment.

```
create.4<-function(elems)
{
  env<-new.env()
  env$dt<-as.data.frame(elems)
  return(env)
}

append.4<-function(env, elems)
{ 
  env$dt[nrow(env$dt)+1,]<-elems
  return(env)
}

access.4<-function(env)
{
  return(env$dt)
}
```

## The test suite:

For convenience I will use one test function to cover them all with indirect calling. (I checked: using `do.call` instead of calling the functions directly doesn't makes the code run measurable longer).

```
test<-function(id, n=1000)
{
  n<-n-1
  el<-list(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
  o<-do.call(paste0('create.',id),list(el))
  s<-paste0('append.',id)
  for (i in 1:n)
  {
    o<-do.call(s,list(o,el))
  }
  return(do.call(paste0('access.', id), list(o)))
}
```

Let's see the performance for n=10 insertions.

I also added a 'placebo' functions (with suffix `0`) that don't perform anything - just to measure the overhead of the test setup.

```
r<-microbenchmark(test(0,n=10), test(1,n=10),test(2,n=10),test(3,n=10), test(4,n=10))
autoplot(r)
```

[image: Timings for adding n=10 rows]

[image: Timings for n=100 rows]
[image: Timings for n=1000 rows]

For 1E5 rows (measurements done on Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz):

```
nr  function      time
4   data.frame    228.251 
3   sqlite        133.716
2   data.table      3.059
1   rbindlist     169.998 
0   placebo         0.202
```

It looks like the SQLite-based sulution, although regains some speed on large data, is nowhere near data.table + manual exponential growth. The difference is almost two orders of magnitude!

## Summary

*If you know that you will append rather small number of rows (n<=100), go ahead and use the simplest possible solution: just assign the rows to the data.frame using bracket notation and ignore the fact that the data.frame is not pre-populated.*

*For everything else use `data.table::set` and grow the data.table exponentially (e.g. using my code).*

Comment: The reason SQLite is slow is that on each INSERT INTO, it has to REINDEX, which is O(n), where n is the number of rows. This means that insert into a SQL database one row at a time is O(n^2). SQLite can be very fast, if you insert a whole data.frame at once, but it's not the best at growing line by line.

Comment: It appears as of R 4.2.1, there's no difference if a `data.frame`'s own row-appending is combined with a custom environment vs. not. E.g. see the performance with this added solution #5: `create.5<-function(elems)as.data.frame(elems);append.5<-function(dt, elems){dt[nrow(dt)+1,]<-elems;return(dt)};access.5<-function(dt)return(dt)`

Answer (score 7):

### Update with purrr, tidyr & dplyr

As the question is already dated (6 years), the answers are missing a solution with newer packages tidyr and purrr. So for people working with these packages, I want to add a solution to the previous answers - all quite interesting, especially .

The biggest advantage of purrr and tidyr are better readability IMHO.
purrr replaces lapply with the more flexible map() family,
tidyr offers the super-intuitive method add_row - just does what it says :)

```
map_df(1:1000, function(x) { df %>% add_row(x = x, y = toString(x)) })
```

This solution is short and intuitive to read, and it's relatively fast:

```
system.time(
   map_df(1:1000, function(x) { df %>% add_row(x = x, y = toString(x)) })
)
   user  system elapsed 
   0.756   0.006   0.766
```

It scales almost linearly, so for 1e5 rows, the performance is:

```
system.time(
  map_df(1:100000, function(x) { df %>% add_row(x = x, y = toString(x)) })
)
   user  system elapsed 
 76.035   0.259  76.489
```

which would make it rank second right after data.table (if your ignore the placebo) in the benchmark by @Adam Ryczkowski:

```
nr  function      time
4   data.frame    228.251 
3   sqlite        133.716
2   data.table      3.059
1   rbindlist     169.998 
0   placebo         0.202
```

Comment: You don't need to use `add_row`. For example:  `map_dfr(1:1e5, function(x) { tibble(x = x, y = toString(x)) })`.

Comment: @user3808394 thanks, that is an interesting alternative! if someone wants to create a dataframe from scratch, yours is shorter thus the better solution. in case you already have a dataframe, my solution is of course better.

Comment: If you already have a dataframe, you would do ```bind_rows(df, map_dfr(1:1e5, function(x) { tibble(x = x, y = toString(x)) }))``` instead of using `add_row`.

Answer (score 2):

A more generic solution for might be the following.

```
    extendDf <- function (df, n) {
    withFactors <- sum(sapply (df, function(X) (is.factor(X)) )) > 0
    nr          <- nrow (df)
    colNames    <- names(df)
    for (c in 1:length(colNames)) {
        if (is.factor(df[,c])) {
            col         <- vector (mode='character', length = nr+n) 
            col[1:nr]   <- as.character(df[,c])
            col[(nr+1):(n+nr)]<- rep(col[1], n)  # to avoid extra levels
            col         <- as.factor(col)
        } else {
            col         <- vector (mode=mode(df[1,c]), length = nr+n)
            class(col)  <- class (df[1,c])
            col[1:nr]   <- df[,c] 
        }
        if (c==1) {
            newDf       <- data.frame (col ,stringsAsFactors=withFactors)
        } else {
            newDf[,c]   <- col 
        }
    }
    names(newDf) <- colNames
    newDf
}
```

The function extendDf() extends a data frame with n rows.

As an example:

```
aDf <- data.frame (l=TRUE, i=1L, n=1, c='a', t=Sys.time(), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
extendDf (aDf, 2)
#      l i n c                   t
# 1  TRUE 1 1 a 2016-07-06 17:12:30
# 2 FALSE 0 0 a 1970-01-01 01:00:00
# 3 FALSE 0 0 a 1970-01-01 01:00:00

system.time (eDf <- extendDf (aDf, 100000))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.009   0.002   0.010
system.time (eDf <- extendDf (eDf, 100000))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.068   0.002   0.070
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets take a vector 'point' which has numbers from 1 to 5

`point = c(1,2,3,4,5)`

if we want to append a number 6 anywhere inside the vector then below command may come handy

i) **Vectors**

`new_var = append(point, 6 ,after = length(point))`

ii) **columns of a table**

`new_var = append(point, 6 ,after = length(mtcars$mpg))`

The command `append` takes three arguments:

1. the vector/column to be modified.
2. value to be included in the modified vector.
3. a subscript, after which the values are to be appended.

simple...!!
Apologies in case of any...!

Answer (score 1):

My solution is almost the same as the original answer but it doesn't worked for me.

So, I gave names for the columns and it works:

```
painel <- rbind(painel, data.frame("col1" = xtweets$created_at,
                                   "col2" = xtweets$text))
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, in a concise answer!