# Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'any' in r studio

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I doing sentimental analysis over the tweets and binding all the analysed data to a data frame **bayes_final**

After i execute the below code, the error is :

```
Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'any'
```

Here is the code,

```
library(sentiment)

bayes_final<-
data.frame(text=character(),emotion=character(),polarity=character(),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (incremented_city_value in 1:cities_length) {

  # # using sentiment package to classify emotions

  bayes_emotions <- classify_emotion(tweets[[incremented_city_value]], algorithm='bayes')


  # # # # using sentiment package to classify polarities

  bayes_polarities = classify_polarity(tweets[[incremented_city_value]], algorithm='bayes')

  bayes_df_polarity = data.frame(text=tweets[[incremented_city_value]], emotion=bayes_emotions[,'BEST_FIT'], polarity=bayes_polarities[,'BEST_FIT'], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  bayes_final <- rbind(bayes_final,bayes_df_polarity)

}
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Just to check, can you try bayes_emotions[['BEST_FIT']] instead of bayes_emotions[,'BEST_FIT'] and the other one also in this subsetting format ?

Comment: @ManishSaraswat I have tried what you said. But it's still the same.

Comment: Please provide a sample data.

Comment: It is probably not causing the error, but using rbind like that is not recommended. See the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/q/20689650/841830