# enter line to an object

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

Hello in R how could I write a function which takes as an input a number at which aline should be entered into an existing object

```
matrix(rnorm(9),ncol=3,nrow=5)
x<-c(1,7,8)
```

Each vector should now be entered into the matrix into the matrix at row 3 (so it should be the new co row 3 .  The other rows would just be a pushed so the old row 3 is row 4 then

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I wrote for that a while back.  I've been using it.

```
#Christopher Barry, 28/01/2015

insertRows <- function(DF, mtx, row){
  if(is.vector(mtx)){
    mtx <- matrix(mtx, 1, length(mtx), byrow=T)
  }
  nrow0 <- nrow(DF)
  nrows <- nrow(mtx)
  ncols <- ncol(DF) #should be same as for mtx
  if(is.matrix(DF)){DF <- rbind(DF, matrix(0, nrows, ncols))}
  if(nrow0 >= row){
    DF[seq(row+nrows,nrow0+nrows),] <- DF[seq(row,nrow0),]
    DF[row:(row+nrows-1),] <- mtx
  }else{
    DF[seq(nrow0+1,nrow0+nrows),] <- mtx
  }
  return (DF)
}
```

Edited to work for matrices and data frames.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this can be :

```
aa<- matrix(rnorm(9),ncol=3,nrow=5)
x<-c(1,7,8)
rbind(aa[1:2,],x,aa[3:5,])
```

A similar solution ot this, actually:
[R: Insert a vector as a row in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651198/r-insert-a-vector-as-a-row-in-data-frame)